# Access 2016 Returning query result in form

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I have a form with a text box that should show the persons age (which is calculated by a query). It works, but only when that text box is active. When any other field is selected, it shows 'TRUE'.

How can I: 
A. Requery each time the DateOfBirth field is updated? 
B. Show the age of the person, permanently, without the value going back to 'TRUE' when the field lost focus?

I tried several things, but none seem to have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: Wrap it in "" to make it a string. I am using the expression in the source field.